# How to code this html on wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, devise

Need some help to code this i add a sample shot of the error, i have tried to add the frame and it doesn't work for me.

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"height="300"src="http://publicidad.dicom.gob.do/banners/medios/blogs/espaciodeprensa/index.html" width="700" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

[error show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PRGd.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Can you please share the code that you think does not work, so that we can help you from there?

Comment: sue... here is:   <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"height="300"src="http://publicidad.dicom.gob.do/banners/medios/blogs/espaciodeprensa/index.html" width="700" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: not working, i have to see what is the problem..

Answer (score 1):

You got no spaces between your attributes. Try this:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="300" src="http://publicidad.dicom.gob.do/banners/medios/blogs/espaciodeprensa/index.html" width="700" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use to text widget than to paste iframe code in text widget.